# Error al hacer un registro en la bd mysql en un host

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Que tal, tengo un formulario, lo he subido a un host, por ejemplo *www.ejemplo.com/registro*  y al momento de registrar me sale lo siguiente

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /home/xxx/xx.xx/prueba/controllerdb.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_query(): No such file or directory in /home/xxx/xx.xx/prueba/controllerdb.php on line 34

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/xxx/xx.xx/prueba/controllerdb.php on line 34

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/xxx/xx.xx/prueba/controllerdb.php on line 35

Warning: mysql_query(): No such file or directory in //home/xxx/xx.xx/prueba/controllerdb.php on line 49

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in //home/xxx/xx.xx/prueba/controllerdb.php on line 49
Invalid query: No such file or directory
```

Este es controllerdb.php

```
    <?php
class DBController {
private $host = "www.xxx.mx";
private $user = "xxxx";
private $password = "xxxxx";
private $database = "xxxx";

function __construct() {
    $conn = $this->connectDB();
    if(!empty($conn)) {
        $this->selectDB($conn);
    }
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
    return $conn;
}

function selectDB($conn) {
    mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
}

function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysql_query($query);
    $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;
}

function updateQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

function insertQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}

function deleteQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
}

    ?>
```

Cabe aclarar que tengo la bd creada en PHPMyAdmin del host.

De manera local me funciona muy bien.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví esto de la siguiente manera:
A la función `connectDB` le agregué la base de datos:

```
function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
    return $conn;
}
```

También a la función para usar la bd, selectDB, le removí la variable `conn`:

```
function selectDB($conn) {
    mysql_select_db($this->database);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si de forma local te funciona bien, pero si la conexión la realizas desde otra maquina y te falla, seguramente es que la maquina con la base de datos no tiene abierto el puerto para poder conectarse desde fuera.

**Revisa si el puerto de conexión a base de datos esta abierto y es accesible para otras maquinas.**

Comment: Gracias por responder, pues no exactamente, le quité algunas cosas y funcionó.